# create dataframe of difference of medians in column based on values of another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,6,3,7,1,5,7),
 class=c('apple','boy','boy','apple','boy','apple','apple','boy'), 
type=c('type1','type1','type2','type2','type3','type4','type4','type4'), 
col1=c(-0.9,0.8,0.7,-0.6,-0.5,0.4,0.3,0.9), col2=c(-6.9,2.8,0.4,-1.6,-0.8,0.6,0.2,-0.1), 
col3=c(6.7,0.9,0.2,-0.7,-0.8,1.6,3.2,0.1))

id class  type col1 col2 col3
1 apple type1 -0.9 -6.9  6.7
2   boy type1  0.8  2.8  0.9
6   boy type2  0.7  0.4  0.2
3 apple type2 -0.6 -1.6 -0.7
7   boy type3 -0.5 -0.8 -0.8
1 apple type4  0.4  0.6  1.6
5 apple type4  0.3  0.2  3.2
7   boy type4  0.9 -0.1  0.1
```

I am trying to create a dataframe which has the same columns (i.e., col1, col2, col3, ...) but the values in it should be `median((data %>% filter(class=="apple"))$col1) - median((data %>% filter(class=="boy"))$col1)` and so on for each `type` for each column.

So, the final dataframe will look like

```
  type col1 col2 col3
type1 -0.1 -4.1  3.7
type2  0.7  0.4  0.2
type3 -0.5 -0.8 -0.8
type4  0.4  0.6  1.6
```

I can do this by creating individual dataframes of each `type` and calculating the difference of medians of both the classes and append the vector to an empty dataframe with `bind_rows()`.

But is there any better and easier method to do this?

Comment: Your sample code (in the paragraph) has too many quotes. If my answer is not right, then please (a) fix your code errors, it can be difficult to troubleshoot coding questions/problems when the syntax *in the question* will not even parse; and (2) expand your sample data so that you have more than one observation in each group, as the median of a single datum is rather uninteresting (and differencing that with itself is ... less so :-).

Comment: @kalki: Please check this : `median((data %>% filter(class==""boy"))$col1) - median((data %>% filter(class==""boy"))$col1)`. Is this correct. Gives 0

Comment: @TarJae, I saw that too, it's likely because each group only has one `"boy"`, the median of a single datum is the datum itself, then subtract it from itself ... is `0`.

Comment: @r2evans thanks for pointing out the typo. I have edited the post to fix it

Comment: Oh yes, that's a *significant* change in the summarizing logic.

Comment: @r2evans and kalki. Please see my answer and let me know what you think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you want is something like this:

```r
data %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarize(across(col1:col3, ~ median(.[class=="boy"] - median(.[class=="boy"]))))
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   type   col1  col2  col3
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 type1     0     0     0
# 2 type2     0     0     0
# 3 type3     0     0     0
# 4 type4     0     0     0
```

though in this instance it will return all `0`s because you only have one `"boy"` within each group.

---

Post question-edit, here's the updated code and results:

```r
data %>%
 group_by(type) %>%
 summarize(across(col1:col3, ~ median(.[class=="apple"]) - median(.[class=="boy"])))
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   type     col1   col2    col3
#   <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 type1 -1.7    -9.700  5.8   
# 2 type2 -1.3000 -2     -0.9000
# 3 type3 NA      NA     NA     
# 4 type4 -0.55    0.5    2.3
```

The `NA`s are because `type3` only has `"boy"`, no `"apple"`.

(At least we aren't comparing `"apple"` to `"orange"`, that would have been rather cliché ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way how you can get your solution: That was a tough!

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    arrange(id) %>% 
    filter(class == "boy" | type=="type1") %>% 
    group_by(type) %>% 
    summarise(across(starts_with("col"), sum))
```

```
  type   col1  col2  col3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 type1  -0.1  -4.1   7.6
2 type2   0.7   0.4   0.2
3 type3  -0.5  -0.8  -0.8
4 type4   0.9  -0.1   0.1
```

Comment: You're missing some of the parens in the sample code, I think it's `median(. - median(.))`.

Comment: TarJae, I've said the same thing in two comments and in my answer. Your alarm at "0" is correct, and that is all the sample data we have.

Comment: @TarJae I have corrected my question, but this solution is still helpful. Could you please explain the `~ median(. - median(.))` part? It seems similar to r2evans' answer.

Comment: (Reload, it changed 7 minutes ago)

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks.!

Comment: @kalki. Please see my update. Now I understand your aim . And you can get your desired output by the provided logic.

Comment: @TarJae Thanks, but I needed the difference between the medians and it seems to be providing the sum.

Comment: `median((data %>% filter(class=="apple"))$col1) - median((data %>% filter(class=="boy"))$col1)`  is same as my code. The trick: 1. `filter`, 2.  `group_by`. So far we have got  `id class type   col1  col2  col3
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 apple type1  -0.9  -6.9   6.7
2     2 boy   type1   0.8   2.8   0.9
3     6 boy   and so on........` . the last line of the code e.g. `summarise(across(starts_with("col"), sum))` is now only relevant for `type1` because only `type1` has 2 lines: the sum of these two lines per column is the difference of the medians. Check it! Cheers :-)